# Ubuntu- encrypted folder for multiple users?

Tags: ubuntu, encryption

It's well documented how to create an encrypted home folder that is decrypted on login. I have a slightly different use case: I want a shared folder (specifically, code repositories) that is decrypted automatically at login for multiple users, presumably part of a specific group.

This needs to support access through the svn+ssh protocol, so user interaction can't be required.